# JavaScript - Calculating values based on an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array, pictured below, which contains a number of values which I would like to do some calculations on a then push to a separate array.

This is is an example of the array and data I an working with:

[image: Original Array]

I would like to push this data into an array called formatted, This array must contain the following information:

**name** - taken from the name form the original array

**min** - the lowest value from the original array

**max** - the largest value from the original array

**Q1** - this is the lower quartile which is calculated from the original array by adding the p30 and p40 values and dividing by 2

**Q4** - this is is the upper quartile value which is calculated by adding the p70 and p80 values together and dividing by 2

**median** - this is calculated by adding the p50 and p60 values together and dividing by 2

This is an example of how I tried to solve this but as seen below I had a error on every value:

```
 var formated = [];
        for(var i=0; i < final.length; i++) {    
            formated.push({
                name: final[i].name,
                min: final[i][0],
                max: final[i].length -1,
                Q1: (final[1] + final[2] / 2),
                Q2: (final[5] + final[6] / 2),
                meidan: (final[3] + final[4] / 2)
            });
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all of the objects always have the same p-values, this is what you'd need:

```
 var formated = [];
        for(var i=0; i < final.length; i++) {    
            formated.push({
                name: final[i].name,
                min: final[i].p20,
                max: final[i].p90,
                Q1: ((final[i].p30 + final[i].p40) / 2),
                Q2: ((final[i].p70 + final[i].p80) / 2),
                median: ((final[i].p50 + final[i].p60) / 2)
            });
        }
```

A more elegant version of the above, using `Array.prototype.map()`:

```
 var formated = final.map(function(item){
     return {
       name: item.name,
       min: item.p20,
       max: item.p90,
       Q1: ((item.p30 + item.p40) / 2),
       Q2: ((item.p70 + item.p80) / 2),
       median: ((item.p50 + item.p60) / 2)
     };
   });
```

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo: Already fixed! A simple mistake in translating the original code to code based on `map()`. Thanks for pointing it out, though.

Comment: @Tex no problem! I see your edit just when I finish commenting! Looks fine now!!

Comment: @CathalO'Donnell Take a look at my corrected example and Jose's correct one using `map()`. That's definitely the method I prefer over the `for` loop.

Comment: how do you know p20 will always have lowest  value and p90 will have highest value?

Comment: @user2181397 It seems very likely from the fact that he was pulling `min` from `final[0]` and was trying to pull `max` from the last key in each object in his original code, from his explanation of how to calculate `Q1`, `Q2` and `median`, and from his data, which appears to be some sort of statistical dataset.

Comment: @user2181397 I assume that the 'p' in the property names stands for something like 'percentile'. If my assumption is correct, the 20th percentile (`p20`) will almost certainly always have values lower than the 30th percentile (`p30`), and so on, up the list.

Answer (score 1):

You have objects with different namings.

What you call

```
final[i][0]
```

Should be something like

```
final[i].p20
```

or similar. 
Same for all other references, infact in `final[i]` doesn't exists a property `0`. So `final[i][0]` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` function for this. `Map` return a new Array :

```js
const array = [
{name : "0006", p20 : 13367.8, p30: 15654.2, p40 : 17199.8, p50 : 18715, p60 : 20285.4, p70 : 22654.6, p80 : 24910.2, p90 : 30394.2}
];

var formated = array.map(el=>({
  name: el.name,
  min: el.p20,
  max: el.p90,
  Q1: ((el.p30 + el.p40) / 2),
  Q2: ((el.p70 + el.p80) / 2),
  median: ((el.p50 + el.p60) / 2)
}));

console.log(formated);
```